# Timer not firing on WatchOS 3

Tags: timer, swift3, watchkit

I'm calling `startTimer()` and getting "start timer" printed in the console, but the scheduled timer never fires. Any thoughts?

```
func startTimer() {
    print("start timer")
    let timerDidFire: (Timer) -> Void = { timer in
        print("timer")
        self.updateLabels()
    }

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: timerDidFire)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that you're executing your timer in **main** thread.
You can check current execution in thread by:

```
print(Thread.current)
```

If not main, call your timer here:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // here is your timer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This below methods are working perfect in WatchOS 3 for Timer.**

```
func startTimers() {
        RefreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(InterfaceController.RefreshData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimers() {
        RefreshTimer.invalidate()
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't address the issue with the block based API

Comment: Can  you give the sample  project to understand clearly :)

Comment: @Shrawan he asks about closure approach, not selector.